# Javascript/Jquery: Find where a sortable/draggable item was dragged from?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a mix of jquery's sortable and draggable, and am having some problems accessing the parent/sender aka where a list item was dragged FROM.

I'm able to access the parent in the draggable drag: or start: however that only happens the first time I drag it out of it its original container. After that, it's never fired. I've been trying to figure out how to get the id of the list an item was dragged from with sortable's receive: but I keep getting undefined.

Additionally, can you post a link of where I can get information on all ui.item and ui.sender, etc? I really can't find the documentation that describes all ui attributes, etc.

Here's my code:

```js
var origin = null;
var newItem = null;
$("#wordBank,.words").draggable({
    helper: "clone",
    connectToSortable: ".sort",
    drag: function getParent() {
        origin = $(this).parent()[0].id;
        console.log("origin = " + origin);
        return (origin);
    
    }
});
$(".words,.sort").sortable({
  connectWith: "#wordBank,.sort",
  change(event,ui)
  {
    //var sender = ui.sender[0].id;
    //console.log("SNEDER = " + sender);
  },
  beforeStop: function(event,ui) {
    newItem = ui.item[0];
    
  },
  receive: function (event, ui) {
    var sendingID = $(this).closest("ul").attr("id");
    console.log("OKOK " + sendingID);    
      ui.item.toggleClass("highlight");
      var currentListID = this.id; //where the item is dropped
      var originatedID = origin; //where item came from
      var itemID = ui.item[0].id;
      var itemContent = ui.item[0].innerHTML; //which item it is (or . 
      //ui.item[0].id)
      var currentListLength = this.children.length;

    //console.log(typeof itemContent);
    $(newItem).attr("id",itemContent);
    
    //console.log(this);
    //alert(ui.helper.attr("value"));


    
      //if current item is dropped in the word bank, remove the list-
      //inline-item
      console.log(currentListID);

      if (!ui.item[0].classList.contains("list-inline-item"))
      {
          console.log("ko");
          ui.item[0].classList.add("list-inline-item");
      }
  
      //console.log(originatedID==="wordBank");
      //console.log(originatedID!=="wordBank" && currentListID 
      //==="trash");
      if (originatedID === "wordBank")
      {
          if (currentListID === "trash")
          {
              ui.helper[0].remove();
          }
          else 
          {
              //console.log("originalID CSS = " + originatedID);
             // ui.helper.css("font-size","10px");
          }
      }
      else if (originatedID !== "wordBank" && currentListID === 
      //"trash")
      {
          ui.item[0].remove();
      }

      console.log(currentListID==="trash" && originatedID==="wordBank")
      if ((currentListID === "trash") && (originatedID === "wordBank"))
      {
          //alert("inHere");
        //console.log(ui.helper.remove());
       // console.log("Now testing the removal: ");
        //works when directly from wordBank
        ui.helper[0].remove();
    }
  }
});
$().disableSelection();
```

```css
.border {
border: 1px black solid;
}

#wordBank {
border: 2px pink solid
}
```

```html
<ul id="wordBank" class="bank1" value = "ok">
 <li id="1" value = "word1" class="words word1">Word1</li>
 <li id="2" value = "word2" class="words word2">Word2</li>
 <li id="3" value = "word3" class="words word3">Word3</li>
 <li id="4" value = "word4" class="words word4">Word4</li>
 <li id="5" value = "word5" class="words word5">Word5</li>
</ul>

<div  id="drop1" class="border sort">1. </div>
<div id="drop2" class="border sort">2. </div>
<div id="drop3" class="border sort">3. </div>
<div id="drop4" class="border sort">4. </div>
<div id="trash" class="border sort">5.  Trash Here </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, i'm not a expert, but $(this).parent() Will return last parent of the object.

If you need the last parent and get the id of then use:

$(this).parent().attr('id');

If the control you are looking is 2 or more parents last you will need to set .parent() two times to get then.

Edit: If you need to get another think use .last('obj') to get then to.

Comment: That doesn't work inside of my sortable's receive. It works inside of my draggable's start: or drag: events, ($(this).parent()[0].id) EXCEPT that's only triggered the first time I drag an item. If I try it in my sortable, using your method it comes up as undefined. Using my method $(this).parent()[0].id it comes up as just nothing.